# Is there a smalltalk implementation of the textile "humane text" format?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo, textile

I like the [textile](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/) 'Humane web text generator' and I'd like to use it in tools like [Pier](http://wwwpiercms.com), but I've not yet come across a Smalltalk implementation. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of one. The question did come up on the pier mailing list a couple years ago... this might provide a little info and if you were so inclined, you could join the pier mailing list and implement...

http://forum.world.st/Textile-instead-of-Pier-Syntax-td118692.html

Answer (score 1):

Some people are using [OSProcess](http://www.squeaksource.com/OSProcess.html) and [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to generate HTML from markup.

I guess you can try the same thing with Textile ?

See http://forum.world.st/I-m-trying-to-call-markdown-as-an-external-process-td2957078.html for more details.

Comment: There's a pure [Smalltalk markdown parser](http://www.squeaksource.com/PetitMarkdown.html) on Squeaksource.